# Sending a raw transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, signature, raw-transaction, sendrawtransaction

I'm trying to send ether from one address to another. I have a valid generated address and a private key for that. I have a node is working on Linux in fullmode and RPC server listening on the default port. According to JSON RPC Wiki I'm trying to create the following transaction:

```
String transaction = "
{
  "from": "my address",
  "to": "an address of a recipient",
  "value": "a value in Wei converted to Hex String",
  "chainId": 1,
  "nonce": 0
}"
```

And then I'm creating a signature like

```
String txData = makeKeccak256(privateKey + transaction.toHex());
```

And sending this string as Hex to RPC server. But I'm getting the following error:

```
rlp: expected input list for types.txdata
```

I've read that the gasPrice and gas are calculating automatically and are optional. So please help me to find out how to send the transaction correctly. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can also sign a transaction using ethereumjs-tx.
Give this try,

```
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');

const rawTx = {
  from: 'Your account address,
  to: 'Recipient account address',
  value: 'Values in wei
}

var tx = new Tx(rawTx);

tx.sign('Your private key in buffer');

var stx = tx.serialize();

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + stx.toString('hex'), (err, hash) => {
  if (err) { 
    console.log(err);
    return; 
  }else{
    console.log(hash);
});
```

To send exact values of nonce and gasPrice use [web3.eth.estimateGas](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#estimategas) and [web3.eth.getTransactionCount](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#estimategas) methods.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What does exactly do that method "sign". Is it a hash calculation with Keccak algo? And same for "serialize", what is it. I just have to use RPC server of Geth and work via TCP socket so I'm filling out headers, json body etc., therefore I need to know internal details :D

Comment: "sign" - it will sign a transaction object using a private key and generate a signature on it. "serialize" - There are two ways to send transaction: sendTransaction and sendSignedTransaction. When private key is not handled by any third party like Metamask, we need to perform serialization before sending.

Comment: Then I do it correctly, I guess? I'm converting Json object with transaction data to hex string, concatenating it with private key data converted to hex string and then calculating keccak256 hash. And then I push this data to sendRawTransaction. But something is wrong...

Comment: Well, I found a reason why it doesn't work - a raw transaction must be encoded to RLP format. It requires nonce, gasPrice, gasLimit, recipientAddress, amount, comment, r, s, v fields in that order. I've read RLP documentation and follow it during transaction creation, but now I'm getting an error "rlp: input string too long for common.Address, decoding into (types.Transaction)(types.txdata).Recipient". The address is valid and encoded properly according to RLP. Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: I have no idea about that. You should ask another question related to RLP issue. It will reach to more people.